# How to POST file API Contents to external API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, sanity

```
export default function Component() {
  const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const [file] = e.target.files!;
    console.log(file);

    fetch("/api/uploadImage", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(file),
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
  return (
    <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

backend code---

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const file = req.body;

  try {
    const { _id } = await client.assets.upload("image", file, {
      contentType: file.type,
      filename: file.name,
    });

    const response = client
      .patch("document_id")
      .set({
        authorImg: {
          _type: "image",
          asset: {
            _type: "reference",
            _ref: _id,
          },
        },
      })
      .commit();

    res.status(200).json(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
}
```

In this code, I can `console.log(file)` on the frontend, and it shows me the file contents. But getting empty object when trying to `console.log(req.body)` on the sever side API. How can I post the whole file object to my API. On the backend I'll upload the image to sanity cdn. So, need the file object for metadata and other stuffs.

Comment: Can you show your backend code

Comment: sure. Let me edit the post

Comment: for file upload why are you using `application/json`... you should use `formdata` for file related apis.

Comment: Check req.files in your backend code instead of req.body

Comment: export default async function handler(
  { req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse }
) {